# What does the --streaming option do in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

[The documentation says that the --streaming flag sets](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params):

"Whether streaming mode is enabled or disabled; true if enabled."

I can't find any explanation of how 'streaming mode' actually changes the behaviour of the pipeline though. If I run a pipeline with this flag set to `true` against a bounded source, the pipeline still shuts down when all the data is read (which was my first hypothesis).

I wonder if there are other behavours that are affected that I should be taking into account when running pipelines.

So - how does the streaming mode affect the behaviour of a Dataflow pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `--streaming` on the pipeline, regardless of the boundedness of the source, autoscaling is disabled by default (it's enabled by default when the pipeline does not have the flag set, and the source is bounded).

I don't know if there are other consequences yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of quick things to note when using Streaming Mode (with reference to Python Apache Beam SDK. I believe it would be the same for Java SDK too)

1. In streaming mode, the data can only be read from Cloud PubSub and be written to Cloud Pub Sub or Bigquery
2. Batch sources (like file on GCS) are not yet supported in streaming mode.

For more refer to: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#it-looks-like-my-streaming-pipeline-that-reads-from-pubsub-is-slowing-down-what-can-i-do